# Can the Web.sitemap file be styled when directly edited?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a large website with a lot of roles per siteMapNode. Assume as a given that the node structure and roles are not changeable to due policy. This is a "Web Application" and not MVC, just in case that makes a difference.

Visual Studio 2010 automatically gives keywords (like "title") a red color, so there is some inherent styling of predefined words. If I know the precise string, I can use Ctrl+F to find the string(s) in the document, but sometimes I need to browse through the document to find what I need.

Here is a subsample of a much larger sitemap document, where I have formatted the document as much as I could using whitespace and tabs.

```
  <siteMapNode
    title="Data Manager Documents"
    roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\Shannon.Pfleiderer">
    <siteMapNode
          title="Skill Journal"
          roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\Shannon.Pfleiderer"
          url="~/DataManager/SkillJournal.aspx" />
  </siteMapNode>

  <siteMapNode
        title="Incident Report"
        roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Clerk">

      <siteMapNode
          title="Add/Edit/View"
          roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Clerk"
          url="http://wales:4885/IncidentReport/IncidentReport.aspx" />
```

.... and so on .....

Is there a way to fine-tune the way the Web.sitemap file appears when I edit the file through Visual Studio? If I could define font style for a predefined set of words, then I could easily scroll through the document to find them, rather than have to browse a document with identical font and color.

***What I have done so far:***

- I did a thorough Google search and found no tutorials -- only the question I asked on the ASP.NET forum (which got misunderstood as an attempt to style a sitemap in an HTML page with CSS).
- I examined the features available in the Visual Studio interface to see if I could luck into a solution (see screenshot). The "output" and "stylesheet" fields did not have any relationship with appearance of the sitemap content.

[image: Screenshot of web.sitemap properties panel]

***My running theory:***

It might be that the answer to the posed question is no -- there is no known way to do this in Visual Studio -- but I have no confirmation of that. Perhaps it is a matter of my not knowing a specific command or stylesheet.

Another possibility is that my question is based on an incorrect premise or set of foundations (in other words, I could be doing it wrong).

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer to the posed question is no.  However, there is a different approach to making it easier to visually browse through the web.sitemap contents. You can move a branch of sitemap nodes in a different file and reference it in the web.sitemap file by use of the *siteMapFile* attribute of *siteMapNode* (source: [ASP.NET Site Maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)).

```
<siteMapNode siteMapFile="MySiteMap.sitemap"/>
```

In a "see also" link, I found this demo.

> For example, you could have a main site map that references a child
>   site map. The main site map could be the following:

```
<siteMapNode  title="Home Page"  description="">
<siteMapNode title="First Level 1"  description="" />
<siteMapNode  title="First Level 2" description="">
  <siteMapNode  title="Second Level 1" description=""/>
  <siteMapNode  title="Second Level 2" description=""/>
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode siteMapFile="child.sitemap" />
```

> The child map could be the following:

```
<siteMapNode  title="Child First Level 1"  description="">
  <siteMapNode title="Child Second Level 1"  description="" />
  <siteMapNode  title="Child Second Level 2"  description="" />
  <siteMapNode  title=""  description="" />
</siteMapNode>
```

I verified this approach and it solves my problem by sitemap content organization.